# Application doesnt run on windows startup with registry C#

Tags: c#, winforms, registry

I have a winform application that I need to start on Windows Startup.My Application just reads data from a microcontroller and displays it in the Windows form.  I have the following code in my application:

```
   //start application on startup
   var path = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run";
   RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(path, true);                    
   key.SetValue("My-App", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
  // start application on startup
```

This code works fine in Windows 7. I was testing this on Windows 10, and it doesnt work. I was looking into the registry path and it gives me this path :

> c:\Program Files\Default Company Name\My-App\My-App.exe

When I paste this path in CMD it gives an error saying this(" ***C:\Program*** ") directory doesnt exist . But if i put the path in double quotes it works:

> "c:\Program Files\Default Company Name\My-App\My-App.exe"

How can I add double quotes to this :

```
 Application.ExecutablePath.ToString()
```

So that it comes up in the registry with inverted quotes to startup the application properly.

Or is there a better way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: "it doesnt work" is not an appropriate problem description.  It has nothing to do with inverted commas.

Comment: I have edited that part.

Comment: @HansPassant why does this have nothing to do with double quotes ?

Comment: @Adds -- Hans said "it has nothing to do with inverted commas".  Inverted commas are *not* double quotes.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i have edited the question with double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Inverted commas...you mean double quotes?  Just do this:

```
string x = "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() + "\"";
```

Note, I have to escape the quotes using backslash `\`.

Comment: It's `‘` and `’`, see [inverted comma](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inverted_comma), but you are likely correct ;)

Comment: @Adds -- There's no commas involved, inverted or otherwise.  You need to use double quote characters.

Comment: When I restarted the computer the application didnt run. The registry key application path does show the "Double quotes" though.

Comment: Explain "didn't run".  What happened, **exactly**?  Please stop being so vague.

Comment: When I double click on the application exe the Windows Form GUI is displayed. When I restart the computer I want the application to run and start displaying the windows form gui, but the windows form doesnt show up, as the application is not running.It is not in the task manager.

Comment: Have you even tried debugging it, i.e. setting a break point, etc?  **What is it actually doing**?  I doubt it just doesn't run.  You need to do some basic troubleshooting.

Comment: The Code creates a registry with the right path and the double quotes in "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run". If I restart my computer the application should execute and start as soon as I log in to windows. It Runs fine on windows 7 where my development environment is. I have debugged there and it works fine. When I deploy or run the exe file on windows 10 and restart the computer , the Application doesnt run when the OS restarts.

Comment: The application is set to run as administrator, I have checked the UAC and it is the lowest. When I double click on the application exe it works fine. It just doesnt start on windows Startup.

Comment: My Application just reads data from a microcontroller and displays it in the Windows form.